# Is it possible to add multiple locations in bulk to a Google Map under My Places?

Tags: xml, google-maps, kml

I have a KML file with 52 locations, but when I import it into Google Maps, I only get the last point.

To replicate, I cut my KML file down to two locations, and I get the same result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Placemark><name>SUNSHINE CHEVRON</name>
<description>HIALEAH
</description>
<Point><coordinates>-80.282852,25.872066,0</coordinates></Point>
</Placemark>
<Placemark><name>SUNSHINE #30028</name>
<description>HIALEAH
</description>
<Point><coordinates>-80.31525,25.883871,0</coordinates></Point>
</Placemark>
</kml>
```

In this case, only Sunshine #30028 shows up on the map.

Is there a way to bulk upload into Google maps. I'm open to using some other service to accomplish this, but it cannot contain any ads.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the [<Document>](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#document) element.

[Without it](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http%3a%2F%2Fwww.geocodezip.com%2Fgeoxml3_test%2Fkmltest_2_SUNSHINE_CHEVRON_a_kml.xml&hl=en&sll=25.877968,-80.299051&sspn=0.029036,0.038409&t=m&z=19), you get one placemark [with it](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http%3a%2F%2Fwww.geocodezip.com%2Fgeoxml3_test%2Fkmltest_2_SUNSHINE_CHEVRON_b_kml.xml&hl=en&sll=25.88387,-80.31525&sspn=0.001815,0.002401&t=m&z=15) you get both.

And to answer the question in the title, go to "My places" in Google Maps, click on "CREATE MAP", then click on "Import".  You can provide either a local KML file or a URL to a KML file on the web, and it will import it into your Google "My places".  You can even import multiple KML files into the same map, then export it again as KML.